# Значения клавиш клавиатуры наоборот

Tags: c++, winapi

Добрый вечер.
Каким образом можно написать программу(WinApi) которая будет работать по реагированию на клавиатуру.
К примеру нажимается 'Q' и программа закрывается или сворачивается.
Или нажатие клавиши 'space' приведет к тому,что в программе будет напечатан символ 'S'.
Вообщем что бы клавиши печатали совсем другие символы или выполняли другие команды.
Если можно пример реализации хоть одной кнопки.

Comment: Ищите любые примеры цикла обработки событий в любом учебнике начального уровня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот пример функции обработки событий на WinAPI, основной код регистрации окошка не привожу, почитайте об этом здесь: http://cppstudio.com/post/9621/.

Конкретно эта программа отлавливает все нажатия с клавиатуры и рисует букву соответствующей клавиши(игнорируя служебные: home, pageup...).

Тут в коде за это отвечает `switch/case`(который принимает `wParam`), там где `case WM_KEYDOWN` вариант `default`. `(char)wParam` это и есть, собственно код нажатой клавиши, ваша задача добавить условия и логику обработки для каждой нужной вам клавиши.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
HDC hDc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
RECT rect;
HFONT hFont;
static char text[2] = { ' ', '\0' };
switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Стучи по клаве!", L"Слышь!", MB_ICONASTERISK | MB_OK);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hDc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        SetTextColor(hDc, NULL);
        hFont = CreateFont(90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Arial Bold");
        SelectObject(hDc, hFont);
        DrawText(hDc, (LPWSTR)text, 1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam) {
            case VK_HOME:case VK_END:case VK_PRIOR:
            case VK_NEXT:case VK_LEFT:case VK_RIGHT:
            case VK_UP:case VK_DOWN:case VK_DELETE:
            case VK_SHIFT:case VK_SPACE:case VK_CONTROL:
            case VK_CAPITAL:case VK_MENU:case VK_TAB:
            case VK_BACK:case VK_RETURN:
                break;
            default:
                text[0] = (char)wParam;
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
                break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(NULL);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
}
return NULL;}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. буду пробовать.

Comment: Что то у меня ничего не получается. С добавлением событий для клавиш, которые не указаны в (wParam).
text[0] = (char)wParam; 
К примеру мне надо заменить вывод той же клавиши Q на W.
Как мне это правильно расписать? Мои варианты вообще не подходят. Хотя компилятор молчит.

Comment: @Petr, ну пишите, что если (char)wParam равен коду клавиши Q, я сейчас не скажу какой там код, поищите в таблице аски кодов, то в text[0] загружайте код клавиши W.

Comment: @Petr, поотлаживайте, понаблюдайте, что приходит в wParam в той или иной ситуации.

Comment: спасибо. буду пробовать. по таблице сейчас все параметры переклацаю.

Comment: Заработало. Запутался просто в этих под параметрах.